# EGit - cannot get exit code

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When cloning a git repository, at the end I get an error: 
*Git repository clone failed. gerrit version is not yet completed, cannot get exit code*

All projects are cloned but eclipse does not see the repository.

Does anybody know what could be the possible cause and ideally how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Which git repository? All of them? Just one?

Comment: @nitind Multiple repositories (SSH not HTTPS).I managed to clone it in git (cmd) and I can fetch and push in Egit no problem. Still not able to clone though. I decided to put it here as I couldn't find any details about this error online.